# School or education in my resume?

Tags: word-usage, formality

I'm filling an employment application, so I want to know what is the most formal way to refer to my education block.

```
Personal information.
-Name: 
-Age:
-Address:
-Phone: 

Introduction & Goals.
<Description>

Professional Experience
-Actual Job
<Description>
-Last Job
<Description>

[Education or Schooling]
-Bachelor's Degree
<Description>
-High Scool
<Description>
```

In my research down the internet, I can see that `Education` is the most used, but I want you to help me if it's the most formal.

Comment: I suggest'Education'.

Comment: Is that anything like writer's block? (A little more context would help if you expect to receive any serious responses to your otherwise off-topic question.)

Comment: @MarkHubbard I don't understand the "writer's block" part... This is like the personal, professional experience or knowledge block.

Comment: I apologize, tachomi. That part was a joke. You need to give us additional information in order to understand the context of your question. What have you already come up with on your own (give us an example)? What research have you done on the internet to help you get other examples you could use or emulate?

Comment: @MarkHubbard I'm filling an employment application and I what to know how to refer to my education block. I wnat to know what's the best practice and formal way to mean that.

Comment: @tachomi- I understand. What have you come up with so far? (e. g., "Bachelor of Science Degree, with a major in Public Administration, Harvard  University, 2015."

Comment: @MarkHubbard I updated the question, I only have the Bachelor Degree, but I want to know what to put in the tittle of that block, Education or Schooling.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you not use "Shooling".  (Or "High Scool", for that matter.)

Comment: Did you read it?

Comment: @tachomi- Definitely use "Education."

Comment: (In the US it should be "Education".)

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean if I read it?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter that much, since, in addition to "scool" you've misspelled "Intorudction" and "Proffessional".)

Comment: @tachomi- My pleasure. Good luck! :-)

Comment: @HotLicks Lol, thanks for that. Of course this was due to the quick update of the question.

Comment: "what is the most formal way" - primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, on a CV or résumé, people use the word "education."  Also, the word would be "schooling," not "school."  "Schooling" is synonymous with "education." "School" is where one goes to get their "schooling," their "education."  In some places and to some people, however, "school" doesn't mean higher education.  Instead, it's associated with "primary school" or "grade school," which makes "education" more uniformly understood and so preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the "school - schooling" correction.